# How to display old and new values in Lightning field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

I have multiple lightning input field and my requirement is to display the old and changed values of the field in separate view. I am newbie to lightning and I am struggling to figure out the concept. Any help highly appreciated.

I started with one field and I have alert box to show the old and new value.

**Component**

```
 <aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
    <aura:attribute name="expenseName" type="String" default="My Expense"/>
     <aura:attribute name="expenseName1" type="String" default="My Expense1"/>
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.expenseName}" action="{!c.expenseNameChanged}"/> 
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.expenseName1}" action="{!c.expenseNameChanged}"/>    

    <ui:inputText label="Expense Name" value="{!v.expenseName}"/>
    <ui:inputText label="Expense Name1" value="{!v.expenseName1}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
   ({
    expenseNameChanged : function(component, event, helper) {
        var newValue = event.getParam("value");
        var oldValue = event.getParam("oldValue");
        alert("Expense name changed from '" + oldValue + "' to '" + newValue + "'");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use onkeypress to get old value on this event it will return the value before pressing keys and to get new value please use onkeyup then it will give new value.

So you need to use two  events onkeypress and onkeyup  and it will work.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of handling this requirement as far as i can think

1. If you are retrieving sobject field value like name from account. you get the value from server and bind that to lightning input and store the name in another attribute. That way one value changes based on user input and another one retains the old value
2. If its from UI directly and not from server then you can keep storing the old value  into another attribute on onchange of lightning input and keep both the new and old value.

Basically it involves using 2 different attributes to store the 2 values

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Is it possible to store the old values for multiple fields in UI. Can you give me a code example to store old and new values of multiple fields

Comment: I have updated my code . I have 2 attribute and 2 handler. If I have 50 fields then I need to create 50 handler and 50 attribute. I know this wrong approach. I am looking for alternate for this.

Comment: No need to have 50 attributes, instead use an attribute of type sobject and then compare fields to find the changed ones.Oldaccount attribute and new account attribute